# Javascript event listener works in browser, not in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am writing a color picker with an RGB slider in jquery mobile for a phonegap application. it works in the browser, but does NOT work when pushed to the phone (using phonegap/eclipse). I don't know how to get javascript console feedback using phonegap, so I am kind of at a loss.

I have tried using ".on .change .live .bind" for the change event listeners and all of them I can get working in the browser, but NONE in the phonegap application.

Heres what it looks like:
[image: Screenshot of browser]

Here is the javascript:

```
$(function () {
$("#red, #green, #blue").change(function () {
    var red = $("#red").val();
    var green = $("#green").val();
    var blue = $("#blue").val();
    var redp = Math.round((red * 100) / 255);
    var greenp = Math.round((green * 100) / 255);
    var bluep = Math.round((blue * 100) / 255);
    $('#redrgb').html(red);
    $('#greenrgb').html(green);
    $('#bluergb').html(blue);
    $('#redpercent').html(redp + "%");
    $('#greenpercent').html(greenp + "%");
    $('#bluepercent').html(bluep + "%");
    $("#swatch").css("background-color", "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")");
    console.log(red);  });  });
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="colorpicker">
    <div id="swatch">
        <div class="rgb swatchtext" id="redrgb">255</div><div class="percent swatchtext" id="redpercent">100%</div>
        <div class="rgb swatchtext" id="greenrgb">140</div><div class="percent swatchtext" id="greenpercent">55%</div>
        <div class="rgb swatchtext" id="bluergb">60</div><div class="percent swatchtext" id="bluepercent">24%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rgbslider" id="sliderred"><input type="range" class="rgbsliders" id="red" value="255" min="0" max="255" /></div>
    <div class="rgbslider" id="slidergreen"><input type="range" class="rgbsliders" id="green" value="140" min="0" max="255" /></div>
    <div class="rgbslider" id="sliderblue"><input type="range" class="rgbsliders" id="blue" value="60" min="0" max="255" /></div>
</div>
```

I am using JQuery-Mobile, phonegap, and right now I'm testing on android, but once I get it working it will be on iOS as well.

Comment: what vs of jquery mobile and phonegap ?

Comment: latest version of everything: JQuery 1.7.2, JQueryMobile 1.1.1, Cordova 2.0.0.  I just downloaded everything last night.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried put this in a $(document).bind('pageinit') block instead ?

Comment: How exactly would I implement that? I'm a little lost with the differences of JQuery Mobile.

Comment: Ya, I've read that a few times already, and I still can't get it working.

Comment: The actual sliders move, it just doesn't change the swatch color or the RGB values in the swatch.

Answer (score 0):

This works!!!!

```
$(function () {
$("#red, #green, #blue").slider({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).bind('change', function () {
            var red = $("#red").val();
            var green = $("#green").val();
            var blue = $("#blue").val();
            var redp = Math.round((red * 100) / 255);
            var greenp = Math.round((green * 100) / 255);
            var bluep = Math.round((blue * 100) / 255);
            $('#redrgb').html(red);
            $('#greenrgb').html(green);
            $('#bluergb').html(blue);
            $('#redpercent').html(redp + "%");
            $('#greenpercent').html(greenp + "%");
            $('#bluepercent').html(bluep + "%");
            $("#swatch").css("background-color", "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")");
            console.log(red);
        });}});});
```

and I had to change type="range" to type="text" in the html inputs.